# Rails send_data throws "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8"... but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I'm using Rails to generate a PDF with the executable wkhtmltopdf and then using send_data to send the result back to the user as a PDF file.

```
 view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths,  {})
 html = "<h1>A heading</h1>"
 pdfdata = `echo '#{html}' | #{RAILS_ROOT}/lib/pdf/wkhtmltopdf-i386 - -`
 send_data pdfdata, :filename => 'readthis.pdf', :disposition => 'attachment', :type => "application/pdf"
```

The PDF is generated properly, but Rails complains `ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in UTF-8)` from the send_data method. Changing it to send "foobar" as `:type => text/html` makes it work, so it's definitely got a problem with `pdfdata`.

I don't understand. Isn't `send_data` supposed to send *binary data*? Of course it's not valid UTF-8. Or am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of ruby are you using ? Does send_file work ? Also did you try disposition => inline ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails assumes UTF-8. Telling it explicitly that it is binary data solves the problem. Thanks for your help.

```
pdfdata.force_encoding('BINARY')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you inspect the variable pdfdata and check whether it is proper or not?

Comment: Well, it certainly contains characters which cannot be properly represented by terminal output or vim, but that's to be expected, right? It's a PDF file.